# How to export a (text) file beside the jar in Gradle

Tags: java, gradle, executable-jar

Normally I develop in C# but for my study I'm using Java and Gradle. I'm trying to export a file beside (so outside) the jar file. In Visual Studio I would set the 'Build Action' to 'Content' on a file and it would end up beside the exe(cutable). I can't find an answer how to do the same in Gradle.

I have the following code for exporting the jar:

```
jar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'Program'
    }
    from {
        configurations.runtimeClasspath.collect {it.isDirectory() ? it: zipTree(it)}
    }
}
```

Above code gives me the .jar file in the build/libs folder. Beside this jar I would like to have my settings.json file.

I hope you can help.

Comment: The C# tool obviously creates a full *installer* for your app. Maven does not do this. You either have to use a 3rd party installer creater (like [NSIS](https://sourceforge.net/projects/nsis/)) and set up a maven plugin to run it or (what I'd prefer) you should copy the file programmatically at application start. In the latter case the appropriate place would rather be `System.getProperty("user.home")` then the location next to the `*.jar` file which is not that easy to get and that might not be writable at runtime...

Comment: C# doesn't make a full installer. It just compiles it into a exe file, so does my gradle (but then a jar). But next to that file I want a file from my source. I think I just add a copy statement to copy the text file into the output folder where the jar is created.